# Tkinter - Display contents of entry on pressing enter

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python TKinter - How do I display the contents of an entry box immedietly after the user has typed in the box and pressed enter?

All of the examples I can see on the web only ever display the contents when a button is clicked.

I want my user to type their name into an entry box, click enter and THEN have a label display their name.

This isn't doing what I want:

```
entername = Entry(window,width=30)
entername.pack()

text3text = entername.get()
text3 = Label(window, text= "hello" + text3text)
text3.pack()
```

Comment: ***" click enter"***: [Edit] your question and show how you do this? Read up on [tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
window= Tk()

entername = Entry(window,width=30)
entername.pack()

text3 = Label(window, text= "hello")
text3.pack()

def grab_entry(event): 
    text3.configure(text = text3['text'] + entername.get())

entername.bind('<Return>', grab_entry) #binds 'enter' to the confirm function

window.mainloop()
```

If you want the label to be displayed after the Entry is given do it like that:

```
def grab_entry(event): 
    text3 = Label(window, text= "hello" + entername.get())
    text3.pack()
```

I would suggest using the first version, but instead of displaying `hello` use some instructions, like `Enter your Name here` or something like that. And then, when the Name is entered show the Hello-Message...

Comment: ***"If you want the label to be displayed after the Entry is given do it like that:"***: This leads to `Label` stacking, on every call to `def grab_entry(...`. Rethink your answer.

Comment: @stovfl given the context of the task, which is to enter a name... I don't see a big problem, usually, you enter your name once, don't you? After that, I guess the given Code is not needed and the `bind` can be replaced or something else